# How to pass nested parameters using angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ransack

I am trying to send a get request to my rails backend using angular. So what am looking for is the request like this

> Parameters: {"location"=>"london", "q"=>{"price_gteq":"33333", "price_lteq":"7777"}}

So in my app.js I tried below code to send the request with the parameters. I am now getting unexpected `/` and the second nested parameter is not showing aswell as seen below.

```
  $http({
        url: "/search.json",
        method: "GET",
        params: {location: $scope.searchLocation, q: {price_gteq: $scope.min_price, price_lteq: $scope.max_price} }
    })
```

This is what i get when I try like above

> Parameters: {"location"=>"london", "q"=>"{\"price_gteq\":\"33333\"}"}

Could someone tell me what am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default angular uses [$httpParamSerializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) which actually can handle nested parameters. Check if your `$http` uses this service. If for some reason it doesn't work, you can write own `paramSerializer` and pass it into `$http` [configuration object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

Also check if `price_lteq` present at the moment, when you send request.

Comment: added paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike' and it worked